# I need to find the position of the first vowel in a string in php

Tags: php

I need to find the position of the first vowel in a one word string. For example.

- `garbage` would return `1`
- `plastic` would return `2`
- `apple` would return `0`

I'm a beginner, so I'm having a hard time with this. I think I need a loop with an array or a regular expression.

Comment: Work off of these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825506/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-detect-and-replace-the-last-vowel-in-a-string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268970/how-to-detect-and-echo-the-last-vowel-in-a-word

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [`strcspn`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcspn.php) function. It will return the length of the string at the beginning not matching any of the characters you specified.

```
$pos = strcspn(strtolower($str), "aeiou"); // and sometimes y
```

Comment: clever in a totally understandable and usable sort of way :)

Answer (score 1):

> `<?php 
>   $mystring="find first vowel in a string";
>
>   $vowel=array();
>
>   $vowel['0'] = stripos($mystring,'a');
>
>   $vowel['1'] = stripos($mystring,'e');
>
>   $vowel['2'] = stripos($mystring,'i');
>
>   $vowel['3'] = stripos($mystring,'o');
>
>   $vowel['4'] = stripos($mystring,'u');
>
>   $min=99999;
>
>   for($i=0; $i<5;$i++){
>
>    if ($vowel[$i] !== false) {
>
>    if($min>$vowel[$i]){
>
>   $min=$vowel[$i];
>
>   }//end if
>
>   }//end if
>
>   }end for
>
>   if($min==99999){
>
>   echo "No vowel found.";
>
>   }else{
>
>   echo "vowel found at position :".$min;
>
>   }
>
>   ?>`

Answer (score 0):

strpos — Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string

e.g==

```
  $email  = 'name@example.com';
  $domain = strpos($email, '@');
  echo $domain; // prints 4
```

Comment: Are you sure is this what he actually asked?

Comment: That solution will find the first occurrence of a particular character , but I need the first occurrence of either a,e,i,o, or u.